# Show content created with javascript to others

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new to web and don't know even if something like this would be possible without using PHP but i'll give it a try.

So my page is fully working on javascript/html/css. This is because i'm trying to make it available offline (yes, i know that php provides a feature appcache, however i've managed to done my things with all javascript so far). User can create a tournament table on my page and can edit it. Is it possible, using only javascript, to display the page one user is editing to the others aswell (something like google docs for example is, that it would be possible to share a link which is only viewable but not editable)? As an user i mean a person who's using the page not an actual "user" who's logged in, since i have no such feature.

Is it even possible to do something like this with only javascript or should i just drop this idea and come back to it when i'm going on the PHP?

Answer (score 0):

You could definitely do something like this in javascript.  You'll have to maintain a database somewhere of current page edits.  One straightforward approach would be to use firebase.  You can store current edits there and display them to other users without having to set up php.

Comment: Yes, but what about linking and displaying items? For example - user creates table, it's in the same url as for the other user, every link created should own a #id? And this #id should expire probably after a day or two.